# A Python function being triggered by Google Cloud Scheduler fails to work on scheduled time but executes perfectly fine when I run it manually

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-scheduler

I have project on Google Cloud App Engine. I have set up a cloud Scheduler to make a GET request every 24 hours to a certain endpoint on the app engine which invokes a simple Python script. The script simply reads a Google Sheet and updates the Cloud Firestore with the data from the sheet. It was working perfectly but for the past couple of days it fails to update the Database on scheduled time and gives an error. But when I trigger it manually from the console it works just fine. So that means the problem is not with my script. Can anyone have an idea what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information in your question, but I think you should analyze logs. In Cloud Scheduler/ Jobs you can find column "Logs" which contain links for every job. You can access Stockdriver Logging for this particular job directly from there.

I hope this will help!